# If you are using Entity Framework, how to do you use the EF Model classes instead of having to make custom View Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.  If one imports all of their existing tables in a database, they can created Entity Framework models.  My question is, how do I actually use these models instead of having to fall back on creating custom View Models of the table data? Here is what I mean:

My understanding is that model classes that Entity Framework automatically generates should not be modified (example: a model of a Products table).  Because of this, I have to create a whole new View Model of the Products table in order to be able to add things like [Display] and [Required] tags to the model so that I can have a custom name displayed to the user (e.g. "Store Products") and validation (e.g. the product name field is required).

See what I mean? Do you always have to manually create a View Model in order to get needed functionality like validation and user-understandable display names?

Side question: the models that Entity Framework automatically creates (based on your existing tables in the database) are called "Domain Models" right?

Comment: Personally, I would create custom models for use in the site created from the EF models.  Your data access should be separate from your presentation layer so they can change independently of each other (I do realise this is more work though).

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you want to make separate view model is because you want to add data annotations then you can just use partial classes

eg: Given an EF generated class

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

you can add a new file with:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyClassMetadata))]
public partial class MyClass
{
}

public class MyClassMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "An Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Some HTML text")]
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

to decorate your EF classes.

Yes, this looks a bit clunky. There might be a neater way to do this in the newer versions.